# HTML/CSS Dropdown in NavBar Menu

Tags: html, css

```
<nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="dropdown tt-megamenu-col-02 <?php echo ($page == "index" ? "selected": "")?>">
                                <a href="index.php">HOME</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown megamenu <?php echo ($page == "categories" || $page == "listing" || $page == "product" ? "selected": "")?>">
                                <a href="categories.php">SHOP</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown tt-megamenu-col-01 <?php echo ($page == "about" ? "selected": "")?>">
                                <a href="about.php">ABOUT</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown tt-megamenu-col-01 <?php echo ($page == "contact" ? "selected": "")?>"><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </nav>
```

I have this navbar and I'm looking to add a dropdown in there with a list of items. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, in snippet

```css
nav{
 display:flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 padding:0px 10px;
}
nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu{
 display:flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
#menuBtn{
 padding:10px;
}
.hiddenlayer{
  background-color: rgba(100%,100%,100%,0.9);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  position:absolute;
  max-height: 0vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
}
.hiddenlayer>div{
  padding:10px;
}
#menuBtn:hover .hiddenlayer{
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<big>LOGO</big>
<div class="menu">
  <div id="menuBtn">ABOUT</div>
  <div id="menuBtn">CATEGORY
    <div class="hiddenlayer">
        <div>
            <a href="#">CATEGORY 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown megamenu">
            <a href="#">CATEGORY 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown tt-megamenu-col-01">
            <a href="#">CATEGORY 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown tt-megamenu-col-01">
            <a href="#">CATEGORY 1</a>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menuBtn">CONTACT</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I actually want it to list HOME SHOP ABOUT CONTACT and then I want to add a fifth option that's CATEGORIES and I want that one to be a dropdown

Comment: same way Replace  'CATEGORIES' at MENU, Now I M going to edit it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>

  <li class="dropdown right">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having to change any of the CSS classes

Comment: yes of course, but you have to add new css as per the css applied .

Comment: What would the CSS have to look like for the dropdown because right now it just shows a regular button

Comment: I hope this might help u: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar